# What is COM in battle mode settings for Mario Kart 8?

Tags: mario-kart-8

When setting up battle mode on Mario Kart 8, I see settings for something called COM. What is that?

Answer (score 8):

COM or Computer are the AI controlling the other karts, changing this will increase or decrease their difficulty.